# Different Output for b=+1 in java

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment

I executed the below program

```
    int b = 0;
    b=+1;
    System.out.println(b);
    b=+1;
    System.out.println(b);
    b=+1;
    System.out.println(b);
```

and got output like 1 always. Why is the value of b incrementing in the first increment and why its not incrementing in the second and third incrementing operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the `=` and `+` symbols. [Unary `+`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) isn't what you want.

```
b+=1;
```

or

```
b++;
```

or

```
++b;
```

Unary plus is `b = (+1);` or just `b = 1`.

Answer (score 4):

you are doing an assignment here with value `+1`

`int` literal allows leading `+` and `-` sign

you  want

```
b += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`b=+1` means `b = +1` here `+` is `unary` operator and you are just giving *sign* to the digit *(which indicates positive value)* while you want *add and assigment operator* `b += 1` means `b = b +1` to increment the value.